# How do I insert a string in the list?

Tags: python-3.x, insert

Among the list elements in the list, I want to insert a comma after converting them into numbers.
please teach me

```
for line in lines:
    # line.split(" \n")
    if "/" in line:
        while "/" in line:
            line=line.replace("/","")
    if "," in line:
        while "," in line:
            line=line.replace(",","")
    # if line.isdigit() == 0 in line:
    #     line=line("{:,}".format(line))

    linelist = line.split("\t")
    line_list.append(linelist)
print(line_list)
```

```
# if line.isdigit() == 0 in line:
#     line=line("{:,}".format(line))
```

Comment: Please add sample data for `lines`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string like `'5'` that you want as a number, you can write `int('5')` and it will be converted to an integer, or `float('5')` for it to be converted into a float. You will have to loop over `linelist` to do this one number at a time.

However, if you want to combine the numbers as one comma-separated string, I would skip the step of converting them to numbers, since you'll be converting them directly back.

If `linelist` is a list of strings, running `', '.join(linelist)` will return a string with all the `linelist` elements separated by a comma and a space.